# string manipulation of multiple vectors

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have three vectors

```
vector<string> usersA = {"a15_afd","a19_afd","a20_afd"}
vector<string> usersB = {"b15_afd","b26_afd","b98_afd"}
vector<string> usersC = {"c94_afd","c92_afd","c99_afd"}
```

I want to check whether the number after the character a exists in other vectors or not.
example: usersA index 0 , is a15_254, i want to check whether 15 exists in the other vectors usersB or usersC.

likewise, i have to check the number after b and c exists in other vectors or not.
what i have done so far. is storing the numbers into a specific vector

```
     vector<string> usersANumber;  // it has the numbers of usersA {"15","19","20"}
     vector<string> usersBNumber;  // it has the numbers of usersB {"15","26","98"}
     vector<string> usersCNumber;  // it has the numbers of usersC {"94","92","99"}
```

i have three for loops
 first loop i check if the numbers of usersANumber are there in the other two vectors,
 second loop i check if the numbers of usersBNumber are there in the other two vectors,
 third loop i check if the numbers of usersCNumber are there in the other two vectors

I find this not efficient. is there any other way I can do this

Comment: Why do you store numbers as strings?

Comment: this is the requirement.

Comment: C++ have many [nice algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) in the standard library, like for example [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), which looks like it could be used for this. It might not be "efficient" as it loops through all vectors once, but it will be shorter.

Comment: Do you need to do this for all the elements?

Comment: @jrok yes I need to do this for all the elements

Comment: Sort the vectors then do `set_simmetric_difference` to find the elements that are present in only one of the two that you're comparing. That'll be O(n*log(n)), I believe.

Comment: I suspect [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) and [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) would probably come in pretty handy for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After storing the numbers into new vectors, you only need to sort those vectors and then search for duplicate items using a binary search algorithm:

```
vector<string> usersA = { "15", "19", "20" };
vector<string> usersB = { "15", "26", "98" };
vector<string> usersC = { "94", "92", "99" };

sort(usersA.begin(), usersA.end());
sort(usersB.begin(), usersB.end());
sort(usersC.begin(), usersC.end());

searchForDuplicateItems(usersA, usersB);
searchForDuplicateItems(usersA, usersC);
searchForDuplicateItems(usersB, usersC);
```

Notice that you only need to compare vectors once, i.e, after going through all items of vector **usersA** to check if they exist in vector **usersB**, there is no need to go through all items of vector **usersB** to check if they exist in vector **usersA**.

The **searchForDuplicateItems** function implementation is shown below:

```
void searchForDuplicateItems(vector<string> &v1, vector<string> &v2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
    {
        if (vectorContainsItem(v2, v1[i]))
        {
            // duplicate item found
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the implementation of the **vectorContainsItem** function, which internally uses a binary search algorithm for efficiency:

```
bool vectorContainsItem(vector<string> &v, string &item)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = (int) v.size() - 1;
    int mid = (right + left) / 2;

    while (left <= right)
    {
        mid = (right + left) / 2;
        if (v[mid].compare(item) == 0)
            return true;
        else if (v[mid].compare(item) < 0)
            left = mid + 1;
        else if (v[mid].compare(item) > 0)
            right = mid - 1;
    }

    return false;
}
```